# How to set up GRUB - Dual Boot of Windows 10 & elementary OS

Tags: dual-boot

I have an SSD with Windows 10 on it, a HDD to go along with it with just data, and now an SSD with elementary OS on it.
During the installation i had some problems, so unplugged the SSD of Windows 10, and HDD's SATA cables, and the installation ended up correct.
Now if I start the PC I don't get the GRUB screen, but the elementary OS login screen instead. I tried to edit the grub config, and update it manually, but that did not help. How could i manage the dual boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to edit the grub config

We don't know what you did configuring grub so maybe you did the following

---

By default Grub comes hidden

to change that just edit

```
$ nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change where it says

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

,to

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

Now update grub

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Reboot to test

You can adjust the timeout in seconds there too.... check the manual

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html

---

Also there's a way to access the Grub menu without editing

Just after the Bios/UEFI post, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> repeatedly. If you fail the timing, reboot and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `boot-repair` from the USB installation media, this has worked for various problems for me in the past:
https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt update
sudo apt install boot-repair
```

This *should* automatically detect your Windows 10 partitions.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it did not solve the issue, after a reboot it prompted me for the encryption key again, instead of the GRUB menu. Does this mean i have to do a clean reinstall?

Comment: @Daniel may as well, if you haven't customised too much. But this time perhaps note exactly what problems you get with the SSD plugged in and edit your question.